# $A$ is a set containing $n$ distinct elements.A non zero subset $P$ of $A$ is chosen.

Tags: probability

$A$ is a set containing $n$ distinct elements.A non zero subset $P$ of $A$ is chosen.The set A is reconstructed by replacing the elements of $P$.A non zero subset $Q$ of $A$ is again chosen.If the number of ways in which $P$ and $Q$ can be chosen simultaneously is $225$.Then find the value of $n.$

---

Probability that the $P$ and $Q$ can be chosen simultaneously is $(\frac{1}{4})^n$
But i could not find the number of ways in which $P$ and $Q$ can be chosen simultaneously.

I surfed this type of questions on this site.I read the related posts but still could not get the answer.Please help me.

Comment: What does "chosen simultaneously" mean?  If it means that the elements chosen for P and the elements that replace them are distinct form those of Q, then why not simply say "There are 225 ways that two non zero subsets are disjoint"  why make is so ... weird?  I guess I simply don't understand the question.

Comment: @fleablood,i am sorry but the question is given in my book in this manner only.

Comment: If the probability that P and Q can be chosen simultaneously (whatever that means) is $(1/4)^n$ (however that was determined) And given that there are $2^n$ subsets, there are $(2^n -1)*(2^n-1)/2$ pairs of non zero subsets, so $(1/4)^n * (2^n - 1)^2/2 = 225$.  Solve for n. (which I don't think is possible.)

Comment: How did you get that the probability of P and Q simultaneously is $(1/4)^n$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469897/a-subset-pmay-be-void-also-is-selected-at-random-from-set-a-and-the-set-a

Comment: I read this question and concluded that the probability of choosing $P$ and $Q$ simultaneously is $(\frac{1}{4})^n$

Comment: The answer is 4 given in my book.

Comment: $(2^n-1)^2=225$ gives $n=4$.Is this possible?@fleablood

Comment: The difference between this and that are that that one allowed empty subsets yours does not.  So the probability P will be different.  The number of total subsets is (2^n - 1)(2^n - 1)/2 so P(2^n - 1)(2^n -1)/2 = 225.

Comment: Hmmm. not sure  There are $2^4$ subsets.  15 non empty.  There are 15 non-empty possibilities for P and 15 non empty possibilities for Q.  But that would mean *all* ways are possible and probability is 1.  I'm missing something and I'm not sure what.  Does "chosen simultaneously" just mean chosen at all?

Comment: I'm very confused by "chosen simultaneous"  I taking it to mean that P and Q are disjoint.  As each element can be either in P, Q, both or neither there are ways for each element to be placed in P or Q so that it isn't in both.  The makes $3^n$ posibilities.  But as we can't have empty sets we can have P empty and there are $2^n$ ways P can be empty. There are $2^n$ ways Q can be empty.  And there is one way both can be empty.  So I figure there are $3^n - 2^{n+1} + 1$ that P and Q can be chosen simulateously.  But that is always an even number (and much less than $(2^n - 1)^2$.  I give up....

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the question to be about the number of ordered pairs of non-empty subsets of $A$. There are $2^{|A|}-1$ non-empty subsets of $A$, and thus $\left(2^{|A|}-1\right)^2$ ordered pairs of them. Equating this to $225$ and solving for $|A|$ yields $|A|=4$.